# json в web роутах laravel - good practice?

Tags: laravel, ооп, api

Как известно, у Laravel есть API, а есть обычные web-маршруты.
К примеру, если я формы отправляю через ajax, то логичнее было бы передавать данные на сервер/обратно в json.
По логике это похоже на API, но в моем приложении его писать не планируется.

**Вопрос к знатокам: является ли хорошим решением возвращать json из контроллера, который не является API-ресурсом?**
Например, метод update просто возвращает "success", без дальнейшего редиректа.

Comment: Почему нет? Бековая часть существует совместно с фронтовой, образуя таким образом единое веб-приложение. Если фронт ожидает JSON, так и сделайте. А хотите универсальности - сделайте 2 контроллера, под API и под редирект. А чтобы не копипастить реализацию сохранения формы, добавьте еще третий класс типа CreateFormAction. У него на вход будут подаваться данные в унифицированном формате из обоих контроллеров.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно возвращать в виде:

```
return $request->wantsJson() ? response()->json(...) : back() // или view или redirect и т.д;
```

Так же, чтобы не дублировать код в каждом контроллере и методе, можно с помощью макросов расширить `Response` фасад. В методе boot сервис провайдера:

```
Response::macro('customResponse', function ($data) {
    return request()->wantsJson() ? response()->json($data) : back();
});
```

далее в контроллере вызываете:

```
return response()->customResponse($data);
```